# selecting some columns with grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have a text file like this

```
Experiment Replica Module Obs
General0 0 scenario.host[12].wlan.mac 189
General0 0 scenario.host[4].wlan.mac 1109
General0 0 scenario.host[2].wlan.mac 1250
General0 0 scenario.host[0].wlan.mac 1150
General0 0 scenario.host[6].wlan.mac 5636
General0 0 scenario.host[102].wlan.mac 16826
General0 0 scenario.rsu.wlan.mac 41030
```

and i am going to calculate the sum of numbers in the column after "scenario.rsu.wlan.mac"

with this script

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILES=$1
EXPERIMENTS=$2
REPLICAS=$3

if [ -z "$INPUT_FILES" ]
then
   echo "usage: $0 input data file.data (willcards allowed)"
fi

echo "Experiment Replica Mean"

find . -name "$INPUT_FILES" | while read file
do
    export MODULE=`echo $file | cut -d- -f 2`
  MODULE=${MODULE/.data/}

  for EXP in $EXPERIMENTS;
  do
    for REP in $REPLICAS;
    do
       DATA=`cat "$file" | grep General$EXP | awk -v replica=$REP 'begin {sum=0;n=0} {if ($2 == replica && $3 == "scenario.rsu.wlan.mac") { sum+=$4;n+=1} } END {mean=sum/n; print mean}'`
       MEAN=`echo $DATA | awk '{print $1}'`
       echo "General$EXP $REP $MEAN"
    done
  done
done
```

notice that the code is work well when i want to calculate the all fourth column but i cannot select the rows that contain the "scenario.rsu.wlan.mac".

Comment: I think you didn't understand your script by yourself. your script has already done the calculation (mean) only for row contains `scenario.rsu.wlan.mac` . but based on the `grep Generalx` and `replica` they are from input parameters. so try to understand the script you have, and spot the real problem you are facing.  in fact,  I feel you just need slight changes on your current script.

Comment: you are doing a cat and then doing a grep, all of which can be done in the awk itself, in awk, by default, variables are initialized to 0, so begin section is just overkill, try to keep it compact, like `print (sum/n)` is enough, mean is not needed, also `$2 == replica` this is probably true only for the first line

Comment: @abasu I **guess** the script was not written by OP.

Comment: @Kent, yeaa, seems so, somebody spent a lot of time to create pipes so that a LONGGG horizontal scroll bar is needed to see the end of the line

Comment: @abasu and i think the `$2==replica` is ok.

Comment: ahh, sorry, i missed the -v part in awk

Comment: Wow! Where to start? Delete that script, start with sudo_O's answer below. Then read the book "Shell Scripting Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach" by Chris Johnson before writing any more shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input file only has one row containing `scenario.rsu.wlan.mac` so I will use the following to demostrate:

```
$ cat file
Experiment Replica Module Obs
General0 0 scenario.host[12].wlan.mac 189
General0 0 scenario.host[4].wlan.mac 1109
General0 0 scenario.host[2].wlan.mac 1250
General0 0 scenario.host[0].wlan.mac 1150
General0 0 scenario.host[6].wlan.mac 5636
General0 0 scenario.host[102].wlan.mac 16826
General0 0 scenario.rsu.wlan.mac 41030
General0 0 scenario.rsu.wlan.mac 34234
General0 0 scenario.rsu.wlan.mac 4453
```

Just test if the third field matches, sum the fourth and print the results in the `END` block:

```
$ awk '$3=="scenario.rsu.wlan.mac"{s=s+$4}END{print "Sum:",s}' file
Sum: 79717
```

There is a lot of bad practices in your script and your question isn't 100% clear so some further clarification would be helpful.